# React hook form + Modal + data-bs-dismiss

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, react-hook-form, tailwind-ui

I want to use a tailwind modal, who open & close with data-bs-dismiss argument.

I put on my button : `data-bs-dismiss='modal'`

But with react hook form, it's doesn't work like i want. If the form contains error or bad input, the data-bs-dismiss was execute and not payed attention to the form errors.

I want close the modal & submit, when the form validation is ok, and contains no other error.

If anyone have a solution.. thank's
My code :

```
const methods = useForm()

return(
    <FormProvider {...methods}>
       <form id={props.id} onSubmit={methods.handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
        <input id='...'> ... <input/>
        <input id='...'> ... <input/>
        <input id='...'> ... <input/>
         ...
        <li>
            <Button
               btnId={`${props.btnContent}Btn`} 
               btnContent={props.btnContent} 
               btnClass='btn' 
               btnType='submit' 
               btnRipple 
               dismiss={'modal'} 
               form={props.id}
             />
         <li/>
       <form/>
   </FormProvider>
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, what you can do is, Instead of using `dismiss` you can check in your `onSubmit` function for any `errors`. And  if the `form` has any `errors` then keep the `modal` open otherwise `submit the form` and close it.

Comment: Yes but how i can close it xD without dismiss (data-bs-dismiss =  'modal') ?( and we using react so no jquery)

Comment: If you are using `tailwind modal` as you said then it has a ` boolean property' called `active` which you can use to show or hide the modal.
`<Modal active={showModal} >`

Comment: sorry but i didn't see it. This modal i use => https://tailwind-elements.com/docs/standard/components/modal/

Comment: try using this https://material-tailwind.com/documentation/react/modals